# Multiple classes for one testclass

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have a testclass with `@Parameters` that looks like this:

```
@Parameterized.Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
    log.info("Starting test class for laan documents");
    controller = new Controller();
    List<Laan> calculations = controller
            .getXMLValues(Controller.Type.LAAN)
            .stream()
            .map(object -> (Laan)object)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    ArrayList<Path> xmlFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    calculations.forEach(s -> xmlFiles.add(s.getXmlPath()));

    log.info("Getting log for " + xmlFiles.size() + " laan files");
    logvalues = controller.getLogvalues(xmlFiles);

    Collection<Object[]> params = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Laan laan : calculations) {
        if(laan.getDocumentType().equalsIgnoreCase("laan")) {
            for(Logfile logfile : logvalues) {
                if(logfile.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(laan.getName())) {
                    params.add(new Object[]{laan.getName(), laan, logfile});
                }
            }
        }
    }
    log.info("");

    return params;
}
```

Most of the objects contains the same variables with different values, but there are some cases where there is nothing to compare with in the `logfile` (which is no problem and in most cases normal). Those cases are handled with a test in the beginning of the test method `assumeTrue(someCondition);`

Now the test class is getting very big and hard to maintain. At the moment there is about 30 test methods in the class and there will be added about 100 new test methods in the upcoming days. I've read that it's bad practise to create a new class and use pointers to other test classes.. So how should I go ahead to and organize my very long testclass?

Comment: What is your task? Don't you mind to use XSLT?

Comment: The xml files are sent through another system. This system is meant to verify the calculations of the system based on the output in the logfile.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your architecture of your test framework. Try to seperate methods by another directories and classes. For example:
If you need to test some functionality like: LoginPage, Dashboard, Email - it doesn't mean that you need to keep all methods in one test class. Create basic api like:
**com.myproject.steps**

1. LoginPageSteps.java
2. DashBoardSteps.java

**com.myproject.suite**

1. TestSuite.java

**com.myproject.scenarious**

1. LoginPageScenario.java
2. DashboardScenario.java

After, if you have methods for working only with Dashboard, move them into DashBoardSteps, and for login methods into LoginPageSteps. After, call them from LoginPageScenario or DashboardScenario, this approach will provide you more comfortable conditions for easy support on future.